# Android: Faster way to compute hash

Tags: java, android, hash

This code will compute the hash of a URI:

```
protected void ShowHash(android.net.Uri uri) {
    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
        DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is, md);
        while(dis.read() != -1) ;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bytesToHex(md.digest()),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return;
}
```

But for a decent sized file (say, a 2MB picture), this will hang for about 10 seconds, which is a ridiculous amount of time.  There is obviously a better way to process the whole file than `while(dis.read() != -1) ;`; how should I go about it?

Comment: Not sure if it can be done faster since I rarely touch hashing, but just a tip: I think it's better to put it on `AsyncTask` or `Thread` instead to prevent locking the UI. [Official doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: Perhaps try the other version of `read()` that reads into an array? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/DigestInputStream.html#read(byte[], int, int)

Comment: Sure, but you're still waiting for about 10 seconds :)

Comment: If I don't want the contents (suppose this is a 3GB file), how do I avoid clogging up memory with a needless copy?

Comment: Maybe read the file in chunks then? Allocate an array of some size and call `read()` however many times you need to get through the entire file?

Comment: Hmm, that might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way is to read the file in larger chunks.  This avoids the overhead of many function calls for each byte.  Of course, you don't want to read the entire file into memory, so you can just use a small buffer:

```
protected void ShowHash(android.net.Uri uri) {
    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
        DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is, md);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while(dis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) != -1) ;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bytesToHex(md.digest()),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return;
}
```

This function returns instantly where the original function takes around 10 seconds.